# Functoriality of $\mathsf{Cu}$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, order-theory, modules

I have always been happy with the proof of the functoriality of the Cuntz semigroup $\mathsf{Cu}$ given in [arXiv:0902.3381](http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.3381), where the isomorphism
$$\mathsf{Cu}(A)\cong W(A\otimes K)$$
is used, $A$ being any C*-algebra, and the functor can be though of as going from the category of C*-algebras to that of partially ordered monoids. I went back to the paper [arXiv:0705.0341](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0341), where the *stabilised* functor $\mathsf{Cu}$ was introduced because I wanted to see how the functoriality of this map was proven within their approach. I might be overlooking something, for the argument that is given there does not seem complete to me.

To abstract a bit, consider a set $S_A$, depending on a C*-algebra $A$, where a relation $\ll$ and an equivalence $\cong$ are defined. We say that $s,t\in S$ are such that $s\precsim t$ if

$$\forall s'\ll s\qquad\exists t'\ll t\qquad |\qquad s'\cong t'.$$

Denote by $\sim$ the antisymmetrisation of $\precsim$, that is say that $s\sim t$ if $s\precsim t$ and $t\precsim s$.

The functor $\mathsf{Cu}$ sends a $*$-homomorphism $f:A\to B$ between C*-algebras to a map $\mathsf{Cu} : \mathsf{Cu}(A) \to \mathsf{Cu}(B)$, where $\mathsf{Cu}(A)$ and $\mathsf{Cu}(B)$ arise as sets of equivalence classes of objects from a set of the kind above w.r.t. the relation $\sim$ (countably generated Hilbert $A$- and $B$-modules in this case). Between $f$ and $\mathsf{Cu}(f)$ there is an intermediate map $f_*:S_A\to S_B$ that is then pushed towards classes to yield $\mathsf{Cu}(f)$.

Now it seems to me that the argument in the second cited paper goes like this:

- prove that $f_*(a)\in S_B$ for any $a\in S_A$;
- prove that $f_*$ preserves the relation $\ll$;
- prove that $f_*$ preserves the relation $\cong$;
- conclude that  $a\precsim b\ \Rightarrow\ f_*(a)\precsim f_*(b)$.

But in order to reach the conclusion of the last point using the results obtained at the previous ones, I believe that one has to make sure that

$$f_*(a)^\ll \subset f_*(a^\ll)$$

(and that, in fact, they are the same set), where

$$a^\ll = \{b \in S_A\ |\ b\ll a\}.$$

However, as far as I can tell, this is not stated anywhere in the second cited paper, nor it is clear to me that this is the case in general. Rather than modules though, I was considering the parallel situation one has in the open projections picture of the Cuntz semigroup described in [arXiv:1008.3497](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3497), the results of which allow to recycle all the *symbolism* above with obvious meaning. From this approach, it seems to me that this can be related to whether the image under a $*$-homomorphism of an hereditary C*-subalgebra is still hereditary.

Comment: You need to check that $f_*$ preserves some sort of suprema. There is some flexibility in how to do this. Say you already know that for each $s\in S_A$ there exists an increasing sequence $s_1\ll s_2\ll s_3\cdots$ with supremum $s$. (In the picture with countably generated Hilbert modules it is clear how to do this.) Check now that the $f_*(s_i)$s have supremum $f_*(s)$. (In the modules picture, that the union of the modules $f_*(s_i)$ is dense in $f_*(s)$). Now you get preservation of $\precsim$.

Comment: @LeonelRobert Many thanks for your comment. The method of proof you suggest seems to involve the knowledge of extra structure of the objects of the category $\mathrm{Cu}$ (e.g. every element is the sup of a rapidly increasing sequence). However here I am interested in showing that $\mathrm{Cu}$ is a functor from the category of C*-algebras to that of positively ordered monoids (perhaps I should have specified this in the question), without any further axioms on the target category. This should be possible, since it is so for $W$.